# "Warning: msg properties can no longer override set node properties" when deploying new Node-RED flow

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I made some changes to my Node-RED flow and saw the following warning pop up when I deployed the flow:

> Warning: msg properties can no longer override set node properties.
>   See bit.ly/nr-override-msg-props

How do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: Hi - so what is your question? It appears you've solved it for yourself.

Comment: My bad, I had meant to answer it. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above [link](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Deprecated:-Message-properties-overriding-set-node-properties) notes that:

> In future nodes and future releases msg.some_property will only be
>   used if the property is not set in the node.
>
> Nodes currently using the override functionality will continue to
>   function in this release but will also receive a warning noting that
>   this behaviour is deprecated.
>
> The core nodes and properties affected by this behaviour are:
>
> http request: msg.url and msg.method 
>   email: msg.to 
>   file: msg.filename

I realized I had `msg.url` set in a `function` node, and the next `http request` node in the flow had the URL set. Once I removed the `msg.url` in the function node, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

or set "Method" to - set by msg.method - in http request node.